# SQL: extracting a number in middle of a cell from a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I need help extracting a number within a number from a different table.
I'll explain:
1st table has phone numbers.
example: `+12125634533, +41542858585`

2nd table has

```
country code | second column
-------------+--------------
1            | usa
41           | switzerland
```

how do I get the operator within the numbers?

example:

`+12125634533` -- operator is `212` (1 is the country code, 5634533 is the phone number - always 7 numbers)

`+41542858585` -- operator is 54 (41 is the country code, 2858585 is the phonen number).

Comment: Is it always going to have 7 digits at the end?

Comment: I'm using SSMS running on sql-server

Comment: yes, it will always have 7 numbers at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the phone prefixes are unique and the phone numbers always start with `+`, then something like this:

```
select t1.*,
       substring(t1.phonenumber, 2 + len(t2.countrycode),
                 len(t1.phonenumber) - 7 - len(t2.countrycode) - 1
                )
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.phonenumber like '+' + t2.countrycode + '%';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e348296ddd6d74f6e7d837b9719bec00) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: close. I still have 1 extra number at the start. 1 (for 1212) and 1 (on the second 141)